# How to "group" events by difference between the row under specified duration between?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The issue I have - is a way to group several events together. The only indicator I have - is the time between the two, three events. A person is doing some tasks (start/end) - everything what is within 14 hrs - is considered to be one working day. Well - it is also over midnight - so date is no option.
I have build a query - which would give me in the first record the indication on how many following records would belong to it. (This is one approach to in).

```
declare @MyTable table
(UserID int, StartDate datetime, FinishDate datetime, GroupCount int);

insert into @MyTable values

('6', '2014-03-18 10:20:00.000', '2014-03-18 13:10:00.000', '2'), --(should take StartDate from this row - and Enddate from next (2) row)
('6', '2014-03-18 13:35:00.000', '2014-03-18 16:25:00.000', '1'),
('6', '2014-03-19 12:05:00.000', '2014-03-19 14:55:00.000', '1'),
('21', '2014-03-14 14:50:00.000', '2014-03-14 15:40:00.000', '1'),
('21', '2014-03-18 13:35:00.000', '2014-03-18 16:55:00.000', '1'),
('99', '2014-03-10 08:05:00.000', '2014-03-10 10:55:00.000', '2'),
('99', '2014-03-10 11:20:00.000', '2014-03-10 14:10:00.000', '1'),
('99', '2014-03-11 10:20:00.000', '2014-03-11 13:10:00.000', '2'),
('99', '2014-03-11 13:50:00.000', '2014-03-11 16:40:00.000', '1');
```

select * from @MyTable

I need to find a way - to group them somehow together - so I have the "min" StartDate and "max" FinishDate.

In the end - it should look like this:

```
declare @MyResult table
(UserID int, StartDate datetime, FinishDate datetime);

insert into @MyResult values

('6', '2014-03-18 10:20:00.000', '2014-03-18 16:25:00.000'),
('6', '2014-03-19 12:05:00.000', '2014-03-19 14:55:00.000'),
('21', '2014-03-14 14:50:00.000', '2014-03-14 15:40:00.000'),
('21', '2014-03-18 13:35:00.000', '2014-03-18 16:55:00.000'),
('99', '2014-03-10 08:05:00.000', '2014-03-10 14:10:00.000'),
('99', '2014-03-11 10:20:00.000', '2014-03-11 16:40:00.000');

select UserID, StartDate, Finishdate, datediff (minute, StartDate, FinishDate) as Duration,
LEAD(startdate,1,NULL) over(partition by userid order by startdate) NextDuty,
  DATEDIFF(minute,FinishDate,LEAD(StartDate,1,NULL) over(partition by userid order by StartDate)) as DifMin

   from @MyResult
```

well - this also depens on a UserID. The GroupCount - was just an idea... but I do not know how to jump for "2" records - to select next start - GroupCount field etc.
2 would indicate - the current and next record belong together, 1 only this actual record.
There would be also 3 or 4 - records belonging together.
All should be done in MS-SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your condition seems to require iterating through the data, one row at a time.  If the condition were "start a new row when there is an 8-hour gap at least", then there are some other possibilities.  But, the logic has to start at the first row for each customer, assigning the group, and then using the logic to increment the group when all tasks within 14-hours have been identified.

The following approach uses a recursive CTE.  The only other SQL alternative I can think of is a cursor.

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by UserId order by StartDate) as seqnum
      from MyTable t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.UserId, t.StartDate, t.FinishDate, seqnum,
             1 as grp, t.StartDate as grp_start
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.UserId, t.StartDate, t.FinishDate, t.seqnum,
             (case when t.StartDate - cte.grp_start <= 14.0/24
                   then cte.grp
                   else cte.grp + 1
              end),
             (case when t.StartDate - cte.grp_start <= 14.0/24
                   then cte.grp_start
                   else t.StartDate
              end)
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.UserId = t.UserId and
              cte.seqnum = t.seqnum - 1
     )
select userid, min(startdate), max(finishdate)
from cte
group by userid, grp      
order by 1, 2;
```

You can see this work [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0622ec/12).

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your answer. Now I run into the problem - as soon as I have more than 100 records... I get The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Any work around for this?

Comment: well - with Option(MaxRecursion 0) there is no more limitation... it just slows down a lot - to get the results of 8000 records - 700 results - takes about 10 sec. - but it works

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but there's a better way to do this. Given that your problem is a bit more complex than standard islands, might I offer:

```
select t.UserID
    , t.StartDate, isnull(b.FinishDate, t.FinishDate) as FinishDate
    , datediff(minute, t.StartDate, isnull(b.FinishDate, t.FinishDate)) as Duration
    , n.NextDuty
    , datediff(minute, isnull(b.FinishDate, t.FinishDate), n.NextDuty) as DiffMin
from @MyTable t
    outer apply (
        select top 1 FinishDate
        from @MyTable b
        where b.UserID = t.UserID
            and b.StartDate > t.StartDate
            and datediff(hh, t.StartDate, b.StartDate) < 14
        order by b.StartDate desc
    ) b
    outer apply (
        select top 1 StartDate as NextDuty
        from @MyTable n
        where n.UserID = t.UserID
            and n.StartDate > t.StartDate
            and datediff(hh, t.StartDate, n.StartDate) > 14
        order by n.StartDate
    ) n
where not exists (
        select top 1 1
        from @MyTable p
        where p.UserID = t.UserID
            and p.StartDate < t.StartDate
            and datediff(hh, p.StartDate, t.StartDate) < 14
    )
```

On the real table, you'll want to ensure this index is in place:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_nameThisIndex ON <@MyTable> (UserId, StartDate, FinishDate)
```

This should get you reliable results, and I've tested with additional data on my side, but haven't done so exhaustively with large sets. The index will be needed for large sets.

Hope this helps.